# Manage multiple connections for user

Tags: node.js, angular, express, jwt

I'm using NodeJs + ExpressJs + Angular 6 for my application and I'm facing a problem.

I have a user U

```
User U:
{
    name;
    email;
    password;
}
```

Let's say he is logged from Chrome, Firefox and a Mobile Phone. Now when user U change his name with his mobile phone for example, I update it to the database and I also want the new user U(with the new name) to be the payload of all signed token from all devices.

What is the best way to handle this ?

Any other suggestions will be great appreciated

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  The same token won't be generated for all three devices normally, and you shouldn't want it to.  Each time the user logs in from a device, a new token will be generated and only part of the data in the token is based on the payload you describe.

Comment: @Paul I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the general answer is basically "you can't".  I would also argue that "you shouldn't".

When you update any portion of the payload, any existing tokens will be invalid because the payload is part of what is signed for verification.  This is an important piece because it ensures that the tokens aren't tampered with.

What will generally happen, then is that all the tokens on all devices are invalid, and the user will be forced to login again on each device to get a new token.  However you handle a logged-out user in your application today is the correct way to deal with this.